# JSON object with non-null values converted to null in MVC Controller method

Tags: ajax, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, data-binding, client-server

Please refer to the picture below...

The **top** part displays the JSON in my client that is being sent to the MVC Controller. I copied this directly from the header in Chrome Dev Tool.

The **bottom** part displays the actual data received by my MVC Controller and how it was bound.

All of the field names in the JSON match perfectly with the field names in the C# object, but yet some values get converted to null and some do not.

Things I note:

(1) In the **bottom** part, I noticed some of the labels have a blue-box icon next to them, and that the labels where the values bound "correctly" have a wrench icon next to them. This might be my first clue.

(2) The C# object that represents the fields in the **bottom** part are made up of all strings, except for partId. partId is an integer.

How do I get the values from the client to show up "correctly" on the server in my controller and NOT be converted to null.

[image: Comparison of the JSON that I am sending to the MVC Controller, and the actual data the MVC Controller binds]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. In my C# object that represents the fields you see in the picture, I converted all to properties. Or in other words, I added "{ get; set; }" to all the fields that did not have it. Now all the values bind correctly when sent to my MVC Controller method.